# ready() in Java testing url too fast

Tags: java, android, html, url, request

When debugging I can confirm 6 out of 9 url connections work. One is dead, and others are sending a exceptions. Question 1:I want it to show either alive or dead, nothing else. Question 2 : when running the test, it tests too fast and it shows all are "dead" links when running (even though I know 6 work). Any suggestions?

```
try{ 
                //Read File
                FileReader file = new FileReader("c:\\blocked\\domains1.txt"); 
                BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(file); 
                BufferedReader rd;
                OutputStreamWriter wr;

                while (true) 
                    { 
                    String line = buff.readLine();                          
                    if (line == null) 
                        break; 
                    else 

                     try
                        {// Test URL Connection
                        URL url = new URL("http://www."+line);
                        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                        conn.setDoOutput(true);
                        wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                        wr.flush();

                       rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                        if( rd.ready())
                        {   
                            //write to output file
                            System.out.println("Good URL: " + line);
                            urlAlive ++;

                            //Write to file
                            Path filePath = Paths.get("c:\\RevisedUrls\\revised.txt");
                                    try
                                    {       
                                        BufferedWriter myWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath.toFile()));                                    
                                        // write the user supplied data to the file plus a line separator.
                                        myWriter.write(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                        myWriter.close();   // immediately close the file when finished with it.
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println(e);
                                    }                   
                        }
                        else// increment dead url 
                            urlDead++;
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                                System.out.println(e.toString());
                            }
                    } 
                buff.close(); 
                }
            finally 
                {
                int totalSites = urlAlive + urlDead;     
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total Number of Alive Sites: " + urlAlive);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total Number of Dead Sites: " + urlDead);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total Number of Sites: " + totalSites);             
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Question 1:I want either alive or dead. I dont want it to throw exceptions